# Why does my program repeat speaking one line C#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech

when i say "quit" to make my program stop, it says the same line a couple of times and then it exits. how could i fix that, so it only says it once?

Thanks!

```
        public void say(String h)
    {
        synth.Speak(h);
    }

    private void rec_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        string r = e.Result.Text;

        if(r == "how are you")
        {
            say("Good and you?");
        }

        if(r == "start youtube")
        {
            say("Opening youtube");
            Process.Start("https://www.youtube.com/");
        }

        if(r == "quit" || r == "exit")
        {
            say("exiting Home A i");
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it listens to itself? When you say "quit" it will say something containing "exit", which in turn is recognized and process repeats... Replace "exiting Home A i" with "Shutting down application. Fasten your belts."

Comment: Thanks that worked! :D